# spread argument union of tuples

Tags: typescript

I have function which returns union type of tuples. I want to pass it to function which accepts all its forms using spread operator `...`.

```js
type TupleUnion = readonly [number, number] | readonly [number, number, string]
function getTuple() : TupleUnion 
function calc(a, b, c?)
const tuple = getTuple();
calc(...tuple)
```

However on last line typescript compiler complains:

```
A spread argument must either have a tuple type or be passed to a rest parameter.ts(2556)
```

I do not want to redefine `calc` function. I need function getTuple to return union type which supports spread operator.

Answer (score 0):

you can use variadic parameter to `calc()` function and passing the tuple into it

```
type TupleUnion = readonly [number, number] | readonly [number, number, string];
function getTuple(): TupleUnion
function calc(...a: TupleUnion)
const tuple = getTuple();
calc(...tuple);
```

Comment: I am aware of this solution. As I said I do not want to redefine calc function as it is used elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

The reason this is occurring is because the `calc` function has fixed parameters. However, `tuple` is an array which can change.

One way you can fix this is by declaring a type with `tuple` at its declaration (this is what the error is telling you to do):

```
const tuple: TupleUnion = getTuple();
```

Another way would be too to add the type to the `calc` function and remove the fixed parameters:

```
function calc(...args: TupleUnion)
```

You would then be able to access the contents of `args` with array syntax just like you would a tuple:

```
args[0]
```

A third way is to assert `tuple` as a constant, but this is hacky and should be considered if nothing else works:

```
const tuple = getTuple() as const;
```

Comment: Compiler is smart enough to evaluate and declare `tuple` type correctly from `getTuple` def in case of first option and as union type `TupleUnion` is not tuple itself typescript (v4.5.5) still complains and does not let you use spread on tuple: `TupleUnion`. 
Second option is not feasible for me as `calc` is use else where. Third option does not work and throws error `A 'const' assertions can only be applied to references to enum members, or string, number, boolean, array, or object literals.`